# How to have bit string in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, byte

I am writting a programme in java. My key is intwritable and the value is a bitstring 0,1.The size of the bitstring may be 1,000,000 (consist of 0 or 1). What type of data i must use that occupies the least space?
Thanks.

Comment: Write your own `Writable` `BitSet`!

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: How?How much space does each value occupy?

Comment: Use the `java.util.BitSet`, it uses a long to store bits, so 64 bits are packed into a long value. You can use the `toLongArray()` method to serialize using the `ArrayWritable` class in Hadoop.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example? I i have 1024 0 or 1, How much space does it occupy?

Comment: Will do, just give a bit of time. 1024/64 * 8 = 128 bytes vs. 1024 bytes as normal byte/boolean encoding vs. 4096 bytes as integer.

Comment: I don't know how to write a custom writable with bitset? which methods do i must implement?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36122/discussion-between-user1878364-and-thomas-jungblut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`java.util.BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to pack your bits into longs, thus receiving some kind of compression. In the mentioned case of your 1024 bits, you can encode the data using 1024/64=16 longs which occupy 8 bytes thus use only 128 bytes in total.

To implement a `Writable` you have to implement the same called interface:

```
public class BitSetWritable implements Writable {

  private BitSet set;

  public BitSetWritable() {
    // default constructor
  }

  public BitSetWritable(BitSet set) {
    this.set = set;
  }
  [...]
}
```

I have added some convenience constructors here, note that the default construct is a must-have for Hadoop's serialization mechanisms.

After implementing the interface, you are forced to implement two methods: `readFields` and `write`:

```
 @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    long[] longs = set.toLongArray();
    out.writeInt(longs.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < longs.length; i++) {
      out.writeLong(longs[i]);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    long[] longs = new long[in.readInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < longs.length; i++) {
      longs[i] = in.readLong();
    }

    set = BitSet.valueOf(longs);
  }
```

This is pretty straight forward, you write the number of longs allocated in the set (only has 4 bytes overhead) and then the long values of the bitset. When reading back, you do the same backwards.

I have added the full files and a testcase to my library on github if you like to directly copy:

https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/writable/BitSetWritable.java

https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/blob/master/test/de/jungblut/writable/BitSetWritableTest.java

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful. i want to "or" two bitsets.i must add a method in BitSetComparable?

Comment: You can use the getter of the Writable's internal bitset and the `or` method of the bitset.

Comment: BitSet doesn't have toLongArray() and ValueOf() method.

Comment: It has, I have added it to my library so I'm pretty sure it compiled: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: How can i see the bitset in bit format? i have set the second bit true but when when i "System.out.println(set)" ,it shows {2}.but i want that it shows 100.

Comment: That is the sparse bit format meaning that index 2 is true. For anything else you need to iterate and output each bit.